# OpenGL Viewport inside of a Viewport

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d, viewport

I'm creating a labyrinth in opengl, and I'm trying to create a minimap. For that, I thought of creating a viewport inside of a viewport. I already tried following a tutorial from Lazy Foo, and I can create the second viewport, but instead of putting a map inside the second viewport, it  puts my whole game there. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you link to the tutorial you are talking about please?

Answer (score 1):

[glViewport](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml) lets you control the part of the screen where the output of your gl  drawing commands will get rendered. It affects the gl commands that you issue after setting up the viewport. So, if you want to render the game to full screen and a minimap to a small portion, then:

1. set glViewport to the entire screen, render game
2. set glViewport to the minimap size and location, render minimap

And do these on every frame.

Answer (score 1):

You need two scenes.

It looks like you know how to render both viewports correctly; so I'll not cover that.

You'll first render the main game view (the first scene), like you're currently doing. Now, instead of redrawing the same objects again for your mini-map, you'll need to define only a *subset* of your game objects so that you can render only those (your second scene) in your minimap.

One way of achieving this is to create a scene graph organized like such:

```
TopNode
+ Map-elements
|+ ground
|+ walls
||- [all the walls objects]
|+ trees
| - [all the trees objects]
+ Dynamic-elements
 + Player-character
 + enemies
 |- [all the enemies objects]
 + loot
  - [all the loot objects]
```

You first render your `TopNode` in your first viewport, which will render everything, then you only render the `Map-elements` node in your second viewport (your minimap). This will only render the static map elements that you want there.

Answer (score 1):

You can render your minimap scene to the framebuffer texture, than render this texture on a 3D quad in front on the screen. This way you can create a cool looking 3D HUD for your game.
You can learn more about this technique [here](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers).